# Python Scrapy, LinkExtracotr doesn't work on some specific url redirecting

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

Actually i am new in Web and Scrapy... So please understand if my question is foolish.

Here is what i want, (A)`http://www.seoultech.ac.kr/`include a linked URL (B)`ctl.seoultech.ac.kr`.
(B)'s domain is subdomain of (A)'s

And my `start_urls` is (A), and than `using allow_domains`=(B) of `LinkExtractor` , the Crawler extracts only one page (B), and

Second, Since the page (B) also includes some URLs with its domain, i expected that it will extract the URLs contained within (B), But it doesn't work, crawling only (B).

URL (B) is redirected to `http://ctl.seoultech.ac.kr/web/index.php` but as i know Scrapy process it itself, i think it is not problem.

the below is my simple code.

```
class SeoulTech(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'seoulTech'
    start_urls = ['http://www.seoultech.ac.kr/']
    allowed_domains = ['seoultech.ac.kr']
    rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("ctl.seoultech.ac.kr",)), callback="parse_item", follow=True),
             )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        itemObj = items.SeoulTechItem()
        itemObj['url'] = response.url
        yield itemObj  # pipeline just store URL as json format
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, URL (B) is redirected to `http://ctl.seoultech.ac.kr/web/index.php`. So LinkExtractor certainly will not address page of URL (B).

Comment: But, when i searched on redirection with Scrapy, it seems to process redirection by default, and when i tried with other URL, it processed redirection, showing redirection log.

Comment: URL(B) is not a valid url. It doesn't refer to any web page. So when you tried to access it directly, the HTTP server definitely would redirect you to its so called "index" page(which is http://ctl.seoultech.ac.kr/web/index.php). Redirection is done by the server. Your choice is only to accept to follow the redirection or not.